# Uninstalling Flirc software from Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, uninstall

I bought and inserted a new Flirc in my Ubuntu machine. I followed the instructions listed here to install the necessary software for this device - https://flirc.tv/ubuntu-software-installation-guide

Here is the output of the installation script -

```
Distribution: debian
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Installing flirc deb-repo...
Running apt-get update... done.
Installing apt-transport-https... done.
Installing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flirc_fury.list...done.
Running apt-get update... done.
Do you want to install the flirc utilities? [Y/n] y
Installing flirc utilities...done.
```

I would now like to uninstall and undo any changes made by this install script. 
I tried using ppa-purge, but it says 'apt-get cannot download list'. I guess it couldnt get the package list from the flirc repo.

So any ideas on how i can list and uninstall the binaries/utilities installed by this thing?

Comment: Part of the install.sh script is: `apt-get install -q -y flirc &> /dev/null` so I assume that it is installed with a deb. Check: `sudo dpkg -s flirc` If it reports installed OK, I will propose an answer.